# Linking two Javascript files to a html document

Tags: javascript, html

Is possible to link two javascript files to one html document? if so can I see some examples

Comment: You can use the `<script>` tag in your HTML document to include as many javascript files as you like.

Comment: I'm assuming you can link one file, so is there something that makes you believe you could _not_ link multiple files in the same way?

Comment: Google: **"link script to html"** Top result https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp Maybe doing some research would help before posting questions like this?

Comment: @NewToJS well I did do some research and I didn't find anything regarding this so i asked here, whats your problem? if its such a bother to answer the question why answer it then

Comment: Hello Anthony! If you see the list of answers grows fast and the vote counter reaches a yearly minimum then, you can be sure your question was too easy and the answer was obvious. That's also a signal for you to search in  stack overflow or in google next time before you ask a question like this. I didn't downvote you because,  we all started with zero. And next time; you will know better. Right? ;-) Kepp your head high and don't hesitate to ask further questions. But make some research before...  All the best... PPK

Comment: @Anthony I didn't say it's a bother to answer your question... hence answering it. I'm making a suggestion for you to research before posting as it will lower the chance of your question being down voted/ignored/voted to be closed. My suggestion can help you when you seek help in the future without having your stackoverflow reputation drop any lower.

Comment: @NewToJS Tbh im not here to get ratings, I'm here to get my questions answered

Comment: @Anthony well some like to build up the reputation so unlock features which enables you to help other people but okay :) at least you got your question answered.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Taken from this exact site:

```
    <head>
    ...
    <script async="" src="http://edge.quantserve.com/quant.js"></script>
    <script async="" src="http://b.scorecardresearch.com/beacon.js"></script>
    ...
    </head>
```